# Error installing Gentoo Prefix on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, prefix, gentoo

I tried to install Gentoo Prefix on Ubuntu 11.10, by following the [Bootstrapping guide.](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/bootstrap-solaris.xml)

But I have an error when I come to the step: `emerge --oneshot --nodeps "=sys-devel/gcc-4.2*"`

- [Output of `emerge --info '=sys-devel/gcc-4.2.4-r01.4'`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1152039/)
- [Output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-devel/gcc-4.2.4-r01.4'`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1152041/)

In [build.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1152020/), I find some error like:

> /usr/include/stdint.h:27:24: error: bits/wchar.h: No such file or directory

Someone told me I should install `build-essential`, but I've already installed that. 
Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

The file /usr/include/bits/wchar.h belongs to the package sys-libs/glibc. Make sure it is compiled and/or properly installed before trying to compile sys-devel/gcc.